# Unable to alter partition table to set logged

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-11, unlogged-tables

I have a partition table that I created `UNLOGGED`. I'm using pg_partman to manage the partition. I then proceeded to load data into it with a COPY command.

Afterwards, I ran an alter table set logged on the parent table but the table still shows as `UNLOGGED` along with all its children.

Is this broken?

You can execute these commands to see the issue:

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE customers(cust_id bigint NOT NULL,cust_name varchar(32) NOT NULL,cust_address text,
cust_country text)PARTITION BY LIST(cust_country);

CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE customer_ind PARTITION OF customers FOR VALUES IN ('ind');

CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE customer_jap PARTITION OF customers FOR VALUES IN ('jap');

CREATE UNLOGGED table customers_def PARTITION OF customers DEFAULT;

INSERT INTO customers VALUES (2039,'Puja','Hyderabad','ind');

INSERT INTO customers VALUES (4499,'Tony','Arizona','USA');

\d+ customers
checkpoint;
alter table customers set logged ;
\d+ customers;
```

Throughout the display of the table details the `UNLOGGED` status doesn't change when running the `ALTER TABLE` command against the parent table. But even when all the child tables have been `SET LOGGED`, I'm still not able to change this on the parent table. Tools like pg_partman will look to the parent table to create the child tables with the "correct" properties.

Comment: I'm having to go to the individual dependent child partitions and altering their logging option. I don't think this is practical or good... I'm still unable to SET LOGGED on the parent partition.

Comment: BUG #15954: Unable to alter partitioned table to set logged

Answer (score 2):

I was recently affected by this bug. I was able to work around by detaching the partitions, re-defining the parent table to enable logging, and then re-attaching the partitions. Continuing with the OP example:

```
postgres=> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM customers;
 count
-------
     2
(1 row)

postgres=> SELECT relpersistence, relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname LIKE 'customer%';
 relpersistence |    relname
----------------+---------------
 u              | customer_ind
 u              | customer_jap
 u              | customers
 u              | customers_def
(4 rows)
```

Enable `LOGGED`:

```
ALTER TABLE customer_ind SET LOGGED;
ALTER TABLE customer_jap SET LOGGED;
ALTER TABLE customers_def SET LOGGED;
ALTER TABLE customers SET LOGGED;
```

Notice that the parent table remains `UNLOGGED`:

```
postgres=> SELECT relpersistence, relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname LIKE 'customer%';
 relpersistence |    relname
----------------+---------------
 p              | customer_ind
 p              | customer_jap
 u              | customers
 p              | customers_def
(4 rows)
```

Manually, detach/attach partitions:

```
ALTER TABLE customers DETACH PARTITION customer_ind;
ALTER TABLE customers DETACH PARTITION customer_jap;
ALTER TABLE customers DETACH PARTITION customers_def;

DROP TABLE customers;
CREATE TABLE customers(cust_id bigint NOT NULL,cust_name varchar(32) NOT NULL,cust_address text,
cust_country text) PARTITION BY LIST(cust_country);

ALTER TABLE customers ATTACH PARTITION customer_ind FOR VALUES IN ('ind');
ALTER TABLE customers ATTACH PARTITION customer_jap FOR VALUES IN ('jap');
ALTER TABLE customers ATTACH PARTITION customers_def DEFAULT;
```

Verify that change worked:

```
postgres=> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM customers;
 count
-------
     2
(1 row)

postgres=> SELECT relpersistence, relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname LIKE 'customer%';
 relpersistence |    relname
----------------+---------------
 p              | customer_ind
 p              | customer_jap
 p              | customers
 p              | customers_def
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a bug.

Following [the bug thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/15954-b61523bed4b110c4%40postgresql.org), I tend to concur with David Rowley's opinion:

It should not be allowed to create `UNLOGGED` partitioned tables.
You can always create an `UNLOGGED` table and attach it as partition to a table.

So your solution would be to set all partitions to `LOGGED`.